# Is a windows service the "correct" choice for interacting with hardware on an embedded system that must run windows?

Tags: c#, windows, service, camera, embedded

I am working on an embedded system that involves collecting data from multiple camera modules over USB. The plan was originally to use a small Linux system, but the Linux drivers for the camera don't support using any of it's features (hardware triggering, shooting raw, certain pixel formats, etc). There is a nice C# SDK provided by the manufacturer and everything just works on Windows. We are now investigating using a small Windows system like the new Intel Compute Stick or a Liva.

I want to write software to collect the data from the cameras as they are hardware triggered by another part of the system, and write the data to a removable disk. It should be remotely controllable via TCP/IP (hard wire). This sounds like something that would fit within the purview of a windows service. Would this be a good way to go?

I'm mostly concerned about running into security/permissions issues. I've been reading things that indicate that services are contained within "non-interactive" window stations, and I'm not sure what that means in terms of being able to access devices etc. The machine running all this is going to be completely headless, so it just has to work all the time. I'm continuing to do my own research into the right thing to do here, but if somebody with relevant experience could give me a suggestion "yes" or "no" along with a good reason why, that would help me out greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- is there any limitations or required privileges to access the hardware/drivers, and which windows identity would allow your service that (elevated) access?
- is any interaction with a user-interface required?

To me, without additional details, it looks like a windows service is going to serve the purpose if there is no user-interface required.

I would also recommend using [Top Shelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) for developing windows services in .Net, as it simplifies and abstracts all the surrounding complexity and lets you focus on what your application needs to achieve instead.

[Note: I'm not affiliated with Top Shelf, or its developers]

Comment: I'm running the test app that comes with the camera SDK from visual studio as my own (administrator privileged) user account, it's not triggering any UAC/etc messages. Security isn't really a concern for this particular component, so I can probably get away with running what I write (be it service or app ultimately) as administrator. I just wanted to make sure somebody wasn't going to pipe up and be like "OH, you definitely can't access the (webcam|usb|media|whatever) subsystem from within the context of a windows service".

Comment: I'm predominately a *NIX developer, can you tell :P?

Comment: windows services are just normal application code, just with a restriction to work without any user-interface component. usually fit for background processing and monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work at a company that did Real Time Vision systems using firewire cameras on windows. The software just ran as an application.  Which just ends up being simpler to deal with and debug.  Most of it was done in C++.  However if you don't have hard real time requirements  ( that software needed to do things within 50ms ) then C# should be fine

You could run it as a service, but there is no particular need to.

Comment: Yeah, the triggering is being done via hardware (a rising edge from a flight control computer to tell the cameras to all snap at the same time), which is the only really real-time bit. The windows system just has to pull data out of the cameras as fast as it can and write it to some kind of (preferably removable) storage. The "interface" to it will just be a few simple commands sent over TCP/IP such as "start/stop collecting data", which will come from the mission management computer.